# How to load a AzureML model in an Azure Databricks compute?

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to run a `DatabricksStep`. I have used `ServicePrincipalAuthentication` to authenticate the run:

```
appId = dbutils.secrets.get(<secret-scope-name>, <client-id>)
tenant = dbutils.secrets.get(<secret-scope-name>, <directory-id>)
clientSecret = dbutils.secrets.get(<secret-scope-name>, <client-secret>)
subscription_id = dbutils.secrets.get(<secret-scope-name>, <subscription-id>)
resource_group = <aml-rgp-name>
workspace_name = <aml-ws-name>

svc_pr = ServicePrincipalAuthentication(
       tenant_id=tenant,
       service_principal_id=appId,
       service_principal_password=clientSecret)

ws = Workspace(
       subscription_id=subscription_id,
       resource_group=resource_group,
       workspace_name=workspace_name,
       auth=svc_pr
       )
```

The authentication is successful since running the following block of code gives the desired output:

```
subscription_id = ws.subscription_id
resource_group = ws.resource_group
workspace_name = ws.name
workspace_region = ws.location
print(subscription_id, resource_group, workspace_name, workspace_region, sep='\n')
```

However, the following block of codes gives an error:

```
model_name=<registered-model-name>
model_path = Model.get_model_path(model_name=model_name, _workspace=ws)
loaded_model = joblib.load(model_path)
print('model loaded!')
```

This is giving an error:

```
UserErrorException:
    Message: 
Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'. The possible reason could be:
1. You are not authorized to access this resource, or directory listing denied.
2. you may not login your azure service, or use other subscription, you can check your
default account by running azure cli commend:
'az account list -o table'.
3. You have multiple objects/login session opened, please close all session and try again.
                
    InnerException None
    ErrorResponse 
{
    "error": {
        "message": "\nOperation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'. The possible reason could be:\n1. You are not authorized to access this resource, or directory listing denied.\n2. you may not login your azure service, or use other subscription, you can check your\ndefault account by running azure cli commend:\n'az account list -o table'.\n3. You have multiple objects/login session opened, please close all session and try again.\n                ",
        "code": "UserError"
    }
}
```

The error is `Forbidden Error` even though I have authenticated using `ServicePrincipalAuthentication`.
How to resolve this error to run inference using an AML registered model in ADB?

Comment: Can you please add more details about the azure ml sdk version.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-configure-databricks-automl-environment#add-the-azure-ml-sdk-to-databricks

Comment: The link is more about running AzureML SDK inside Databricks (Running Databricks Notebooks). I wish to run python scripts from AzureML using DataBricksStep. Just use ADB as an inference compute target.

Comment: The AzureML SDK version is 
1.18.0

Answer (score 0):

The Databricks workspace need to be present in the same subscription as your AML workspace.
This [notebook](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/machine-learning-pipelines/intro-to-pipelines/aml-pipelines-use-databricks-as-compute-target.ipynb) demonstrates the use of DatabricksStep in Azure Machine Learning Pipeline.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model.model?view=azure-ml-py) is the Model class register.

Comment: The forbidden error is being thrown even though the Databricks workspace is present in the same subscription as my AML workspace. I have followed the notebook steps only. 
https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/issues/1266
https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/issues/1265